# nodejs export function on require

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this line of code on some ExpressJS route:

```
var test = require('../app/test')('dev');
test.getData(); //this fails saying: typeError getData() is not a function
```

My test file looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(env){

  var mod = {
  'field1': 'asd',
  'field2': 'asd2'
 };

 mod.getData = function(){
  return 'data';
 };

 return mod;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just return the `mod`. `return mod`. Also `mod.getData() = function(){` should be `mod.getData = function(){`

Comment: Yes, typo sorry, same result.

Comment: Can you please post more code? Maybe your whole project in zip file?

Comment: Correcting you question based on the answers and comments is a really bad thing. The way your code in the question looks like right now should neither throw the above error, nor would the answer provided below solve the problem if it really exists with the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 2 Mistakes :

1/

You may define `filed1` & when you call you use `field1` **==> Typing Error**

2/

You need to write your package that **returns object which has an atttribute `getData` which is another `function`** like the following :

```
module.exports = function(env){

  var mod = {
  'filed1': 'asd',
  'field2': 'asd2',
  'getData' :function(){

       return 'data';
     }
 };

 return mod ;


};
```

---

## Explain :

- `require('../app/test')`  return `function(env){ ....`
- `require('../app/test')('dev')` call  `function(env){....}('dev')` ==> It returns the output of `function(env){....`.
- This output should be an object (`mod`) that contains as attribute `getData` & its value should be a function to be able to call  `require('../app/test')('dev').getData()`

  ---

## DEMO :

```js
test=function(env){

  var mod = {
  'filed1': 'asd',
  'field2': 'asd2',
  'getData' :function(){
    
       return 'data';
     }
   };
 
 return mod ;


};

  console.log(`Can i call "test.getData()" ?` )
try{
   test('dev').getData(); //!--- Call like this 
   console.log('yes')
}catch(e){

   console.log('No : ',e)
}
   
 console.log(`Can i call "test('dev').filed1" ? => `,test('dev').filed1 ==='asd' );
```

Comment: But this way I lose mod data.

Comment: @mdv : No , it is accessible from getData function.. You will not lose IT

Comment: But if from outside I want to use test.field1 //asd and test.getData() ?

Comment: OK... see now the answer ,after updating it according to your requirements.. And check **Explain** block to understand more how it works

Comment: Tried that, same result

Comment: **Really!!** see demo .. it will be added after a while

Comment: that'ts it. somehow calling test('asd').getData() works, you have my upvotes good sir.

Comment: Another error :you define  `filed1` HOWEVER you call  `field1` @mdv

Answer (score -1):

Here is the full source code.

**test.js :**

```
module.exports = function(env){

  var mod = {
    'filed1': 'asd',
    'field2': 'asd2',
    'somefunction' : function () {


    return 'data';

  }
  };


  return mod;
};
```

index.js

```
var test = require('../test');
test().somefunction();
```

The problem is you are trying to access the object's property called getData.
getData is already defined as a property of the mod object. So if you want to access it, you need to delete the parenthesis. test.getData is enough. However, getData is defined as a function.
Also test.js is exported as function.
So you will need to access the test() then invoke the function within the test() by getData();

Comment: `test.somefunction`  would not call the function assigned to property `somefunction`  it would just access it. You will alway need parenthesis to call a function (except if you defined a getter or setter function, for this property). The error says that the value stored in the property `somefunction` is not a function.

Comment: You are right. I managed to fix the error message however, I did not test to make sure the function was actually invoked. I will edit my post.